# Does someone can explain me this line of C Code (Pointer Arithmetic, bit shift)?

Tags: c, pointers, binary, bit-shift

Let `*c` be 32bit in Memory and `xmc[]` array of 32bit in memory (abstract: Network packet)

```
xmc[0] = (*c >> 4) & 0x7;
xmc[1] = (*c >> 1) & 0x7;
xmc[2] = (*c++ & 0x1) << 2;
xmc[2] |= (*c >> 6) & 0x3;
xmc[3] = (*c >> 3) & 0x7;
```

What do the lines `xmc[2]` of code do to the Value (thought in binary)?

I tried to look up the arithmetic, but I failed understanding the part beginning from `*c++`.

EDIT: Added more context for clarification

Comment: If we skip the pointer, and use a normal `int` variables instead, would that make any difference? Like e.g. `int temp1 = c[0]; int temp2 = temp1 & 0x1; int temp3 = temp2 << 2; xmc[2] = temp3; c = c + 1;`

Comment: "What does this line of code do to the Value (thought in binary)?" Nobody knows since we don't know the type of `c`, which is extremely necessary information in order to answer the question.

Comment: Understanding how the bits and bytes flow though this expression is reasonable straightforward.  The more interesting question is, *why* is someone extracting the low-order bit, shifting it left by 2, and storing it in `xmc[2]`?  What does `xmc` mean?  Those are the things you need to try to understand in order to figure out what this code is really doing.

Comment: @SteveSummit this code snipped is from the GSM Kernel (TU Berlin (Germany)). It is a part of the extraction routine for a network packet.

Comment: @Builderhummel Without the context nobody knows what this code is doing.:)

Comment: So it's clear that this code is grabbing bits out of the packed structure pointed to by `c`, and placing the extracted values into the array `xmc`.

Answer (score 2):

**Dereferencing and increment:**
First, you are taking the value stored at the address pointed by the `c` pointer and incrementing the address.

**Bitwise AND with a mask:** A bitwise AND (`&`) is done with a mask of value `0x1` (decimal `1`), which means that only the least significant bit is taken out of the value stored at the address `c`.

Think about it like that: You can have a variable on 4 bits, called `a`, with a decimal value of `3` (binary `0011`) and you are doing a bitwise AND between `a` and a mask of decimal value `2` (binary `10`), also on 4 bits (so `0010`):

a = 0011

b = 0010

Bitwise AND (`a & b` or `a & (0x10)`) will compute an AND between each two bits from `a` and `b`. First bit in `a` is `1`, first bit in `b` is `0` => least significant bit in the result is `1 & 0 = 0`, go on with the second bits of each variable, leading to the second least significant bit in the result being `1`, and so on...

`AND` with such a mask is typically used to take a certain bit (or a group of bits) from a value stored in a variable. In your case, your code takes the least significant bit stored in `a`.

**Left shift:** The left shift `<<` takes the least significant bit two positions to the left (e.g. from `0001` to `0100`), adding 2 bits on `0` to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that we operating on a unsigned 32 bit value. Then code

```
xmc[2] = (*c++ & 0x1) << 2;
```

is equivalent to

```
uint32_t tmp1 = *c;          // Read the value that c points to and
c = c + 1;                   // increment the pointer c
                             // These two lines is the *c++ part

uint32_t tmp2 = tmp1 & 0x1;  // Make tmp2 equal to the least significant bit of tmp1
                             // i.e. tmp2 will be 1 if tmp1 is odd and
                             // tmp2 will be 0 if tmp1 is even

uint32_t tmp3 = tmp2 << 2;   // Make tmp3 equal to tmp2 shifted 2 bits to the left
                             // This is the same as:  tmp3 = tmp2 * 4

xmc[2] = tmp3;               // Save the result in xmc[2]
```

In pseudo code this means:

```
If the value pointed to be c is odd, set xmc[2] to 4
If the value pointed to be c is even, set xmc[2] to 0
Increment the pointer c
```

Answer (score 1):

Today's date could be said to be 20230215.

If you have that as a number, you could extract the components as follows:

```c
n = 20230215;

y = n / 10000 % 10000;
m = n /   100 %   100;
d = n /     1 %   100;
```

The code in question does the same thing. It's extracting four values (`a`, `b`, `c` and `d`) spread over two bytes.

```
c[0]                              c[1]
  7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0     7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | a | a | a | b | b | b | c | | c | c | d | d | d |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Since we want to extract bits instead of digits, we need to use powers of two instead of using powers of ten. When dealing with powers of two, `>>` can be used in lieu of division, and `&` can be used in lieu of `%`.

To extract `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, we could use the following:

```c
n = ( c[0] << 8 ) | c[1];

xmc[0] = ( n >> 12 ) & 0x7;
xmc[1] = ( n >>  9 ) & 0x7;
xmc[2] = ( n >>  6 ) & 0x7;
xmc[3] = ( n >>  3 ) & 0x7;
```

The posted code takes an approach that avoids calculating `n`, but it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`++` is a post-increment operator in C language, and it would be the last operation before assigning a value to the left of the `=`.

```
xmc[2] = (*c++ & 0x1) << 2;
```

This statement could be considered to:

1. de-reference : `*c`
2. bit-wise AND : `*c & 0x1`
3. left-shift   : `(*c & 0x1) << 2`
4. post-increment : `c++`
5. assign to left of = : `xmc[2] =` the result of the 3rd step.

But, the compiler would optimize these operations by its design and might increase `c` before the bit-wise AND operation by utilizing the registers of CPU and stacks in the memory. i.e. differences might be found in the final assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code could be more easily read if it were, equivalently:

```
xmc[0]  = (c[0] >> 4) & 0x7;
xmc[1]  = (c[0] >> 1) & 0x7;
xmc[2]  = (c[0]       & 0x1) << 2;
xmc[2] |= (c[1] >> 6) & 0x3;
xmc[3]  = (c[1] >> 3) & 0x7;
```

(And then, if later code depended on `c` being advanced, this could be followed by a standalone `c++`.)

It looks like `xmc[0]` is taken from three particular bits of `c[0]`, and `xmc[1]` is taken from three other bits of `c[0]`.  Then the next field straddles a word boundary, in that `xmc[2]` is composed by putting together one bit from `c[0]`, and two bits from `c[1]`.  Finally `xmc[3]` is taken from three other bits of `c[1]`.

[@ikegami's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75459756#75461438) has more of the details.